# porting ALSA app from CentOS to Debian

Tags: alsa

I have a C++ app that records from a USB audio device. It was originally written on a CentOS 6.2 machine and I'm working to port it to Debian 6. It compiles and runs fine but nothing is being recorded.

What I've looked for:

- `alsamixer` shows that the relevant input levels are correct
- I can use `arecord` to get audio from the device ( IE the device is working )

What's changed (not sure if any of this matters):

- moved from CentOS to Debian
- moved from x86 to ARM
- device is now id 1 instead of 0

Im not sure what params to check next. The issue seems to be that my (formerly working) app isn't getting any input to the SND_PCM_* and SND_CTL_* libraries.

--> I would post code but there is a great deal of it. I'm not sure what would be relevant.

Suggestions?

EDIT:
device name:

```
[130311.091118] input: Fi3001A USB Audio Device as /devices/platform/orion-ehci.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.3/input/input2  
[130311.103994] generic-usb 0003:04D9:2832.0003: input,hiddev0: USB HID v1.10 Device [Fi3001A USB Audio Device] on usb-orion-ehci.0-1.3/input3


# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Set [C-Media USB Headphone Set], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Show the code that calls `snd_pcm_`* functions. (What do you need the `snd_ctl_`* functions for?)

Comment: Gak. There's pages and pages of SND_PCM calls to setup the connection and build the recording. None of it hits any errors which is what's making me so curious. I'm wondering if I'm specifying the device ID correctly. The volume and mic capture are seemingly set ok but no sound is produced. I send 'hw:1,0' to the PCM calls for this device. That's the same as when I use 'arecord'.

Comment: If `arecord` works, and your program does not, try removing all `snd_ctl_`* calls.

Comment: the CTL_ calls are what I use to set the volume and mic capture. Those seem to be working (I watch the values in alsamixer)

Comment: What do you actually mean with "nothing is being recorded"?

Comment: There is no sound coming into the application. The source code was copied directly from a working CentOS installation to this ARM machine. All that I did was rebuild the executable.

Comment: What do you actually mean with "no sound"? No samples? Zero-valued samples?

Comment: Zero valued samples - at the appropriate rate though.

Comment: Please show the output of `arecord -l` and the exact device name you're using.